# Unable to use the Page Object in a Test Method. (TestNG)

Tags: webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I m somebody who to new to Automation. I m currently learning Selenium Webdriver with JAVA along with Page Object Model pattern. When I experimenting with the few lines of code I got myself strucked at one point. I created a separate class file for the Page Elements which has the below code.

```
    public class SamplePage {

    WebDriver Driver;

    public WebElement Gmail_Email_TextBox = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']"));

    public WebElement Gmail_Email_Next_Button = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']"));

    public SamplePage(WebDriver Driver) { //This is a constructor.

        System.out.println("Constructor");

        this.Driver = Driver;
    }
}
```

When try call the above page in another class I get java.lang.NullPointerException. Pls find the code below.

```
    public class SampleTestMethod {

    WebDriver Driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void BrowserLaunch() throws InterruptedException {

        Driver = Browser.LaunchMozillaFirefox("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1");

    }

    @Test
    public void TestCase1() {

        SamplePage Sample1 = new SamplePage(Driver);

        Sample1.Gmail_Email_TextBox.click();

    }
}
```

Pls clarify me on this. The constructor is not being called at all. This is what I have observed.

Answer (score 1):

Class fields like `Gmail_Email_TextBox` and `Gmail_Email_Next_Button` are evaluated as null **before** constructor's call and never changed afterwards. That is why.

Simply put: initialize those fields in a different place.

You can add a `@FindBy` annotation to each of them and then just use `PageFactory`:

```
SamplePage samplePage = new SamplePage();
PageFactory.initElements(driver, samplePage);
```

[Further info on this.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

Follow naming conventions and use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Instance variables are initialized before constructor calls.
Check this out to see it yourself:

```
public class Example {

    private String instanceVariable;
    private String anotherInstanceVariable = instanceVariable + " appended.";

    public Example(String instanceVariable) {
        this.instanceVariable = instanceVariable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example("The first one");
        System.out.println(example.anotherInstanceVariable);
    }
}
```

`instanceVariable` is like your `driver`. `anotherInstanceVariable` is like any of your `WebElement`s.

Comment: Hi...thanks for your rapid response.....So u mean to say that created WebElement is initialized as Null, before the Constructor is executed...According to my knowledge I thought that on creation of Object of the Class "SamplePage" only the initialization will happen so only I passed the Driver of "SampleTestMethod" as a argument for the "SamplePage" constructor....I might be wrong too....Please correct my understanding on this....

Comment: Instance variables are initialized before constructor calls. I have added an example to demonstrate this.